# How can I add additional parameters to an Angular2 error message

Tags: javascript, angular

I have inherited some code and I'm new to Angular2.  I think this is also using ReactJS.  I want to provide additional information in the error feedback.  But the error handling is a function that returns a pwf error and I'm not sure how to do it.  The code is using a common pattern.  Here is the caller.  The part I am interested in is the Catch, where it calls the function **this.handleValidationError**

```
validate(id: string, mode: string): Observable<Hs2ImportModel> {
   let reqData = {
       importId: id,
       mode: mode
   };
   let body = 'req=' + JSON.stringify(reqData);
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

   return this.http.post(
       this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/service/import/validate',
       body,
       {headers: headers, withCredentials: true}
       )
       .timeout(1000*60*11).retry(0)
       .map(this.mapDetails)
       .catch(this.handleValidationError);
}
```

and here's the function

```
private handleValidationError (error: any) {
    let origError = ErrorUtils.errorAsString(error);
    return Observable.throw(new PwfError('Error Validating Files. ' + origError, 'INTG-VAL-001'));
}
```

I want to be able to provide additional information like id, mode, and a couple of other things, but I can't see how to pass them into hnadleValidationError so that they can be part of the Pwf error message that gets returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about Angular, but could you pass the details to the handler like this?

```
.catch((error) => this.handleValidationError(error, reqData));
```

or in old money:

```
.catch(function(error) {return this.handleValidationError(error, reqData);});
```

Just add the extra parameter to your `handleValidationError` function.

Comment: The 2nd one is close, but I'm getting a TS syntax error on function, saying Argument of type '(error: any) +> void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable.........  There's more, but the bottom line and the source of my true confusion is that the function shows this parameter of error: any, but in the existing, working code (as well as the samples it was derived from), no parameter is passed in the call.

Comment: The other answer might be better. Try `.catch(function(error: any) {.....});`. Note that your code isn't calling the handleValidationError function, you're giving the catch function its name to call if necessary. The catch function will supply the error argument when it calls your function.

Comment: It needs the return keyword. I've edited the answer.